# Deserialize multiple xml elements to single object property

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following xml

```
  <Amendment.Text>
    <Page>4</Page>
    <Line>4</Line>
    <Bold>It is a </Bold>   
    <Italic>Beautiful Day</Italic>
    <Bold>In London</Bold>
    <Italic>17 June 2015</Italic>   
</Amendment.Text>
```

I want the `<Bold>` and `<Italic>` element values to be deserialized to a single 
string array property

My serializable class is as below and its not working.

```
[Serializable]
    public class AmdTextType
    {

        public string Page { get; set; }

        public string Line { get; set; }


        public string[] Content { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: Choice [doesn't work like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).  As it's name suggests, it's one or the other.  I don't think there's a built-in way of achieving this, you'd need to implement `IXmlSerializable` yourself.

Comment: Thanks , I have taken out the Choice option

Answer (score 0):

Why not calculate it from the original elements:

```
[XmlElementAttribute("Italic", typeof(string))]        
public string Italic { get; set; }

[XmlElementAttribute("Bold", typeof(string))]
public string Bold { get; set; }

public string[] Content { 
    get {
        return new string[] { this.Italic, this.Bold };
    }
}
```

Comment: Bold and Italic appear multiple times

Comment: Bold and Italic appear multiple times and its important to preserve the order when deserializing to Content string array

Comment: Well, if they were array elements, your could keep all of the bold and italics in the right order (independent of each other)...Do they always alternate?  Or, is it a free-for-all where they could be?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach.  I got most of this by using the **Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes** in Visual Studio.  This also includes an array of names in case you need to refer back to what is bold or italic

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot("Amendment.Text", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class AmendmentText
{
    [XmlElement("Line", typeof(int))]
    public int Line { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Page", typeof(int))]
    public int Page { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Bold", typeof(string))]        
    [XmlElement("Italic", typeof(string))]        
    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("ContentName")]
    public object[] Content { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ContentName")]
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public ContentName[] ContentName { get; set; }

}

[XmlType(IncludeInSchema = false)]
public enum ContentName
{        
    Bold,
    Italic,        
}
```

Comment: I think this does exactly what you requested.  Have you tried it?